# troubleshooting visible issues in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I made Excel automation using xlwings.
Even if I use xw.App (visible=False), if I use Excel for other tasks locally, I've noticed that the Excel window I'm working on in automation keeps turning on and off.

How can I solve this phenomenon?

```
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
   wb = xw.Book(REPORT_TEMPLATE)
   wb.sheets[0].name = self.report_date.eng_month
   ws = wb.sheets(self.report_date.eng_month)
   ws['B6'].options(pd.DataFrame, header=0, index=False, expand='table', numbers=float).value= date
   ws.range('B5', 'O5').api.Copy()
   ws.range('B6', f'O{5 + len(country_code_product_report.index)}').api.PasteSpecial(Paste=-4122)
   ws.range('B5', 'O5').api.Delete(xw.constants.DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp) 
   wb.save(REPORT_DIR + file_name)
   wb.close()
```